# How to position absolutely positioned element relative to ref position

Tags: reactjs, positioning, refs

I've got a bit of a problem here, hope I get help :0
well I am building a pretty little App on React and I have a navbar which includes an absolutely positioned div and two images for now... I have refs on these images and I want this navbar div to be positioned with the same top coordinates upon render...
Here is how I'm trying:

this code sets top state property to refs position:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApi();
    this.setState({
      scrolling: { top: this.first.current.offsetTop },
    });
  }
```

this is basically navbar

```
let { top } = this.state.scrolling;
<div className="map__left-column__logos">
        <img
          ref={this.first}
          onClick={this.linkContainerClick}
          className="img-svg"
          src={pin}
          alt="pingreen"
        />
        <img onClick={this.linkContainerClick} src={logo} alt="logo" />
        <div
          ref={this.myRef}
          className="link-container"
          style={{ transform, top }}
        >
          <div className="link-container__upcurve"></div>
          <div className="link-container__wrapper"></div> 
          <a href="#" id="container-href">
            {" "}
            <img
              style={{
                top: img1,
                transition: "all linear .2s",
              }}
              className="img-svg"
              src={chosenImg}
              alt=""
            />
          </a>
          <div className="link-container__downcurve"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the linKContainerClick function trying to calculate where to scroll after I click the images

```
linkContainerClick = ({ target }) => {
    let id = target.offsetTop;
    let pixel = id - this.state.scrolling.top;
    this.setState({ innerHtml: target.alt });
    this.setState({
      scrolling: {
        ...this.state.scrolling,
        transform: `translateY(${pixel}px)`,
      },
    });
  };
```

The problem is that on the first render of the App the link-container element is misplaced by 20 pixels... after refresh it moves to the right place

[image]

Comment: could you please create this http://codsandbox.io

Comment: I don't know how to use it or arrange files on codesandbox :(

Comment: sorry I had a typo it's https://codesandbox.io. You can import the files directly from github or you can use it and copy and paste the code as you see fit. It's just like VS code. In this scenario we need to be able to reproduce to identify the problem. If we can't reproduce we can't help you.